# How can I have a function argument that takes an iterator with items that are owned and ones that are borrowed?

Tags: rust

I would like to do the following and allow my `perform` function to take an iterator with `&usize` or with `usize` items as below.

```
fn perform<'a, I>(values: I) -> usize
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a usize>,
{
    *values.max().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    // Works.
    let result = perform(v.iter());
    print!("Result: {}", result);
    
    // Does not work: `expected `&usize`, found `usize``.
    let result = perform(v.iter().map(|v| v * 2));
    print!("Result again: {}", result)
}
```

Playground example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0e80af7a720c894558ef03f6c7abd72).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, by making your function *more* polymorphic, we actually get the behavior for free. Your `perform` works for any `Ord` value.

```
fn perform<'a, I, T>(values: I) -> T
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
    T: Ord,
{
    values.max().unwrap()
}
```

Now `usize` is `Ord` and so is `&usize` (by a blanket `impl` that makes references to any orderable type orderable).

Answer (score 2):

Another way may be accepting owned values in `perform` like this:

```
fn perform<I>(values: I) -> usize
where
    I: Iterator<Item = usize>,
{
    values.max().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    // Works.
    let result = perform(v.iter().map(|x| *x));
    print!("Result: {}", result);

    // Does not work: `expected `&usize`, found `usize``.
    let result = perform(v.iter().map(|v| v * 2));
    print!("Result again: {}", result)
}
```

Comment: Good point. But `.map(|x| *x)` can be written more self-evidently as [`.copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) (for `Copy` types) and [`.cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) (for `Clone` types).

Comment: Using this `.copied()` was actually the solution I ended up using in my real code for other reasons however the answer I marked correct seems to be the canonical answer to my question.